Why does Argentina GDP per capita relatively declined in the last 100 years?
I would like to know if there is an academically well accepted theory on this question.
I know 3 'hand-waving' explanations:

It was rich in the past indeed, but with a small population. It was a kind of frozen meat emirates. As times passed and the population grew, the PIB per capita grew very slowly, at a smaller rate than the present developed countries. So it is now a middle-income instead of developed Country.

From the decade of 1930, the military tried to transform an agrarian nation in a powerful Country, building steel, oil and electricity industry, what helped to industrialize the Country. But the project eventually failed due to the small internal market and an industrialization not driven to the world market.

In the 10 first post war years, General Peron badly mismanaged the economy. Even after his overturn in 1955, the peronism ideology remained as a curse, not allowing the Country to thrive.


I think that the theme is important when we look at the gulf oil states, and its perspectives to have the same GDP per capita of Syria or Jordan 100 years from now, when the oil becomes much less relevant that today.
